# How to filter an object's associations when json serializing it in a rails app?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

How would you filter an object's associations when json serializing it in a rails app?

Imagine:

- `Foo` `has_many` `Bar`
- Any given `Bar` can be active or inactive (has a property `is_active`)
- Foo has a method `active_bars`
- The JSON API to fetch a `Foo` should return active bars only
- Feels like the concept of active / inactive should be hidden from clients

Where and how would you implement the filtering and what key name would you use in the response?

Current ideas:

1. Use default json serialization and return active_bars in a key called `active_bars`. i.e. `foo.as_json({methods: [:active_bars]})`. The downside is that it uses a key named `active_bars` so the concept of "active" is now exposed in the API.
2. Have the controller customize the json in a utility method so that `active_bars` is put in the json with the key `bars`. The downside is that we now need to remember to use this utility method if we need to serialize a `Foo` in a different API endpoint later.
3. Override `Foo.as_json` so it always returns `active_bars` in a key called `bars`. The downside is that our default json format is starting to diverge from our actual structure. Unclear what to do if we ever wanted json with both `bars` and `active_bars`. Maybe OK? Maybe we should consider `as_json` as the public format?
4. Override `Foo.as_json` so it takes a custom option (`:foo_active_bars_only`) and only formats it like that when asked. Downside is using a custom option to a rails API we don't control. Maybe OK.
5. Other options?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a gem such as `jbuilder` so that I could have view files that render my JSON. I find this easier to build, read, and share across the app.

My `show.json.jbuilder` file for fetching a Foo would have this inside:

```
json.bars @foo.active_bars do |bar|
  json.title bar.title
  json.description bar.description
end
```

(this will list the active bars under the key 'bars')

If a `Foo` is also returned nested in another JSON response somewhere else, I would pull this rendering logic out into a partial called `_foo.json.jbuilder` and use that partial in the above `show.json.jbuilder` file as well as in the other place, so that they are rendered with the same key names.